# Passing data from several VC's to a last one in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Description]

As you can appreciate in this pic we have an App with three different VC's and a Last one with some variable data depending of the options selected on the previous ones.

So, for instance, in this case the user had selected a blue color, a suited style and a L as size.

Our idea is to pass data from the first VC, second VC, and the third VC to the gaps in Last VC.

Any suggestions? It would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model class where you can store those properties in :

```
class MyChoices {

var color : String? // or you could use enums for each of them
var style : String? // that would be a better choice, but for the
var size : String? // sake of simplicity I use strings in this example

}
```

then you pass a variable of type MyChoices from one VC to another in your prepareForSegue method

**EDIT (some more info, see answer from FactorJose)**

In VC 1 add your variable

```
class VC1: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nextOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var colourLabel: UILabel!

var choice : MyChoice?

...
```

and then further on :

@IBAction func redButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

```
colourLabel.text = "Red colour selected"
choice.color = "Red"
```

}

for all those IBActions.

then in your prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as! VC2
nextVC.choice = self.choice
}
```

VC2 and VC3 are very similar again

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I'm pretty new coding in Swift.
this is a class of type NSObject right?

Comment: no just a class you define yourself, no need to subclass NSObject, a plain model class (Model-View-Control = MVC). In your models you store your data, in your Views you put wat the users see, and the Controller is the glue that's between them

Comment: if(segue.identifier == "segue") {
    
   
    
    
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! lastVC
    
    vc.passColor = self.color

Comment: that's the way to pass around, but I would not just use different properties each time, but create a model class with all the properties and then have a variable of that type and pass it around

Comment: sorry for repeat Glenn . I have modified the question below

Comment: Nice one Glenn!!! I have almost ready. I am having an error in line: lastVC.choice = self.choice . And it's the following: Instance member 'choice' cannot be used on type lastVC. This error appears too when we send data to another VC instead of the last

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pic]

Hi all! As you can appreciate in this pic we have an App with three different VC's and a Last one with some variable data depending of the options selected on the previous ones.

So, for instance, in this case the user had selected a blue color, a suited style and a L as size.

Our idea is to pass data from the first VC, second VC, and the third VC to the gaps in Last VC.

Any suggestions guys? It would be very appreciated

Code :

```
class VC1: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var nextOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var colourLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    nextOutlet.hidden = true

}

@IBAction func redButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

    colourLabel.text = "Red colour selected"

}


@IBAction func blueButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    nextOutlet.hidden = false

    colourLabel.text = "Blue colour selected"

}

@IBAction func greenButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    nextOutlet.hidden = false

    colourLabel.text = "Green colour selected"

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {}
}
```

VC2 and VC3 are the same as VC1 (same outlets and buttons)

lastVC

```
@IBOutlet weak var colourLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var styleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sizeLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And the last class to store the strings

```
import UIKit

class MyChoices {

var colour : String?
var style : String?
var size : String?
}
```

What can we do?

Comment: @Glenn sorry for repeat Glenn

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to Glenn's answer is to use [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/). Think of it like a mini *key-value* database for [`PropertyList`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html)s.

You can add a new key-value to it with

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(clothingColor, forKey: "Clothing Color")
```

And then retrieve a previously saved key-value by doing

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let clothingColor = defaults.objectForKey("Clothing Color")
```

Since the user defaults is shared and stored in disk, the information will persist across your different view controllers. It also respects encapsulation, which is good object orientation practice, since your size controller won't have to know anything about color or style and vice versa.

Comment: Yes you can use NSUserDefaults, but I'd rather see that as persistent storage (like writing to disk) while here it's actually passing a variable around... I prefer to do such things in memory as it's less overhead (and faster on slower devices)